# Byref argument type mismatch

Tags: vba

Type `=Test2(5)` into Excel after you put the code into a module. Why does this give me a `Byref argument type mismatch` error?

If in the start of `Test2` I do one line to create my arrays:

`Dim X1(5), X2(5) As Double`, then it'll work. But when I use `b` from the function's argument list, I have to `ReDim` (because `b` is a variable, not a constant), which then causes the error.

```
 Function Test1(a As Double)

 Test1 = a * 2

 End Function

 Function Test2(b As Integer)
 Dim X1(), X2() As Double
 ReDim X1(b), X2(b) As Double
 Dim i As Integer

 For i = 0 To b
     X1(i) = i
     X2(i) = Test1(X1(i))
 Next i

 Test2 = X2(1)
 End Function
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This:

```
Dim X1(), X2() As Double
```

only declares `X2()` as double, `X1()` will store the type of `b` (integer) instead of `b` converted to a double (and so prevent passing `As Double`).

To make them both double you must repeat the type declaration;

```
Dim X1() As Double, X2() As Double
ReDim X1(b), X2(b)
```

Which will mean the correct double type is passed to `Test1`